# UIButton Title does not appear or is cut - bottom most label only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uibutton, storyboard

I have a view with a number of buttons. The issue persists regardless whether I have 3, 4 or 5 Buttons. The one most bottom (with the highest y coordinate) does not show its tile. 
By playing around with the coordinates I found out that the title is sort of cut. See the screenshots for details.

All that I changed between those examples are the y coordinates of the buttons. 
It always happens to the button most down in the screen.

[image: All on the same level is just fine]

[image: The lowest two appear empty]

[image: When there is just one that is the lowest, then this one appears empty]

[image: When the difference in y coordinate is smaller then the text height, then the text seems to be cut off somehow.]

Additional information: 
I am using storyboard. 
The View hierarchy:

```
- UIView (The default empty UIView that is linked to the view controller's self.view)
--- UIScrollView
------ UIImage (The background image. Deleting it does not change anything)
------ UIButton
------ UIButton
------ UIButton
-------Lots of constraints, automatically generated.
```

Comment: Are you laying this out in Interface Builder or in code? Can you post the code / a picture the view hierarchy (ie. the tree on the left hand side of IB)?

Comment: @HampusNilsson, I added the information to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not nail it down to its reason. The way I solved it was deleting those 3 buttons and creating them again in IB (Storyboard).

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the title from `Plain` to `Attributed` for all the UIButtons that are suffering from this problem. Then you can change them back to `Plain` and it should solve this (odd) issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will try that when ever the problem re-occurs.

Comment: In my case it only works when title is attributed. When I try to change to plain it shows it cut.