# Xcode Storyboard textview error getting cut in middle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, uitextview

I have a strange error in Xcode 5.0.2.

I just made a new project with the tab bar template. In the views, there is a textview. It is for some reason cut in the middle (see pic below).

I also have same problem with other projects. I have not tampered with the project in any way yet.

Anybody has an idea why and how to fix it?

Thanks!

EDIT: extra screenshot

[image: screenshot from xcode]

[image: attributes]

[image: size]

Comment: please provide screenshot for size and attributes inspector...

Comment: It is factory from the New Project Templates (Tabbed Application)... have not touched anything...

Comment: look at the constraints... may be because of that... not sure why this is happening... but if its working properly in app, i would say ignore it... between, what is version of xcode you are using?

Comment: and just to update, I hate Auto-Layout.. if you don't really using Auto-layout, ignore it.. don't use it...

Comment: It is not the contstraints. I hate Auto-Layout too (although i heard that WWDC'13 session 406 video should change my mind)... but still nothing :( (it is 5.0.2. had the problem since 5.0 in 2 different macs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is known with Apple and merged with another BUG. Hope they will fix soon.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue.  I noticed if I changed the View -> Mode from the default "Scale To Fill" to "Aspect Fill" it fixed the issue.  Oddly, changing it back didn't cause the issue to resurface, so it definitely seems to be a bug with the interface builder in Xcode.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried (in Xcode 5.1) and it didnt help. I tried to make a bug report, but they just answered that they are merging it with another error they have. It is not that irritating, but still :) Thanks for your suggestion though :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing some time ago and asked here on SO. 
In my case it was caused by Buttons with text, not text view.

I found out that the line of the horizontal cut was related to the vertical position of the otehr buttons.

I did not solve it therefore I deleted all UI elements from that view (only 3 in my case) and re-created them. That is, of course just a workaround but it worked. The app still works nicely.

After I did so SO user Bio Cho suggested the solution to change the text from plain to attributed and back to plain.. To late for me to try it, but you could give it a try. See [UIButton Title does not appear or is cut - bottom most label only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440834/uibutton-title-does-not-appear-or-is-cut-bottom-most-label-only)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I tried the suggested workarounds but with no avail. It seems that if there is a "new line" in the text (alt+enter) then the error comes....

Comment: The thing is, on the iphone / simulator, the textview is not cut. only in xcode

Comment: I tried removing some of the text and re-typing but it did not make a difference. Unless the newline managed to hang around? The only thing that fixed it for me was deleting the UITextView entirely and re-adding it. Looking at the diff, the only difference I see is that the newly added text view has this: `<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>` which the original text view does not.

Comment: @Step, don't just remove the text. Remove the buttons. Save, build and re-create them.

Comment: @HermannKlecker What do you mean? There aren't any buttons. There's a UITextView and a UILabel. Removing the text view was the only way I managed to 'fix' this in both places. I could have tried other solutions programmatically to force the textView's properties into shape, but it doesn't seem worth it at this point.

Comment: Btw I did try changing the text type from plain to attributed. Made no difference at all.

Comment: Apologies. In my case it was buttons. IN my case removing them and creating new ones did help. I hope it helpf for you too.